# Progressive and Stationary Waves Amplitudes confusion

Tags: waves

In my mechanics lecture, my professor mentioned that standing waves have nodes and antinodes, which is correct.

Then he mentioned that in progressive waves, all the points have the same amplitude.

I am confused.

How is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

I think what he meant is at any point in space of a progressive wave the medium vibrates with the same amplitude.  This is not to say at any instant in time all points of the medium have the same displacement from equilibrium.  By contrast, in a standing wave the amplitude vibration of the medium is different at different locations e.g. zero at nodes.

Comment: So all points on a wave move by the same amplitude on a progressive wave?

Comment: In the context of comparing standing waves and progressive waves the short answer is "yes" **but**  typically a progressive wave will decrease in amplitude as the moves away from the source, any changes in the medium could also affect the amplitude.

Comment: Confused as to why I got rated down to -1 for a reasonable question that I was confused on by a random online user that doesn't like my post, but thanks very much for your answer!